# How to write a select statement that can match 1 of 3 parameters across multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, subquery

My MySQL is rusty and I can't figure out how to get this query to return what I'm looking for.  I first thought to just use joins but that gave me less results than it should have.

I have four tables: users, users_roles, content, subscriptions
I need to select the users' ids (uid) from the users table when it matches one of three parameters:

1. users.uid = users_roles.uid
2. users.uid = content.uid WHERE content.type=article
3. users.uid = DISTINCT subscriptions.uid

Only one out of three of these parameters needs to be met, not all of them, and it is ok if it only meets 1 or 2 or all 3.

Sample Data:

Users table -

```
username=abc, uid=123, email=example@example.com
username=def, uid=124, email=test@test.com
username=nfc, uid=432, email=test2@test.com
username=jui, uid=999, email=spam@account.com
```

User roles table -

```
uid=123, role=1
uid=432, role=1
```

Content table -

```
cid=1, uid=432, data=x, type=article
```

Subscription table -

```
uid=124
```

The query should return all users in the user table of the example data above except for uid 999 since that uid is not in user roles, content, or subscriptions table.

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data and desired results.  Your SQL may be rusty, but your question doesn't do a good job of explaining what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand your question, following statement should do it:

```
SELECT 
    uid
FROM
    users
WHERE
    -- there's a uid in table users_roles
    uid IN (SELECT ur.uid FROM users_roles ur)
OR
    -- there's a uid in nodes with node.type is your article input value (I assume)
    uid IN (SELECT node.uid FROM node WHERE node.type = <article>)
OR
    -- or lastly your uid is in the simplenews table
    uid IN (SELECT s.uid FROM simplenews s)
```